# Read large lines in huge file without buffering

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

I was wondering if there's an easy way to get lines one at a time out of a file without eventually loading the whole file in memory. I'd like to do a fold over the lines with an *attoparsec* parser. I tried using `Data.Text.Lazy.IO` with `hGetLine` and that blows through my memory. I read later that eventually loads the whole file.

I also tried using *pipes-text* with `folds` and `view lines`:

```
s <- Pipes.sum $ 
    folds (\i _ -> (i+1)) 0 id (view Text.lines (Text.fromHandle handle))
print s
```

to just count the number of lines and it seems to be doing some wonky stuff "hGetChunk: invalid argument (invalid byte sequence)" and it takes 11 minutes where `wc -l` takes 1 minute. I heard that *pipes-text* might have some issues with gigantic lines? (Each line is about 1GB)

I'm really open to any suggestions, can't find much searching except for newbie `readLine` how-tos.

Thanks!

Comment: You are using Pipes.Text.IO for input rather than Pipes.Bytestring+ decoding as the library advises. The error message is from the text library which is making a judgment about system decoding for each chunk. I assume it is saying it can't understand the chunk according to whatever it thinks the encoding is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code uses Conduit, and will:

- UTF8-decode standard input
- Run the `lineC` combinator as long as there is more data available
- For each line, simply `yield` the value `1` and discard the line content, without ever read the entire line into memory at once
- Sum up the `1`s yielded and print it

You can replace the `yield 1` code with something which will do processing on the individual lines.

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-8.4 --install-ghc runghc --package conduit-combinators
import Conduit

main :: IO ()
main = (runConduit
     $ stdinC
    .| decodeUtf8C
    .| peekForeverE (lineC (yield (1 :: Int)))
    .| sumC) >>= print
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the best place to ask, but when I do a foldC in place of sumC over my parsed lines on a 3 int constant size monoid, it seems to blow out all my memory again. Am I leaving anything out? I also tried foldlC.

Comment: Nevermind, did a deepseq instead of seq and everything worked fine

Answer (score 3):

This is probably easiest as a fold over the decoded text stream

```
{-#LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
import Pipes 
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P
import qualified Pipes.ByteString as PB
import qualified Pipes.Text.Encoding as PT
import qualified Control.Foldl as L
import qualified Control.Foldl.Text as LT
main = do
  n <- L.purely P.fold (LT.count '\n') $ void $ PT.decodeUtf8 PB.stdin
  print n
```

It takes about 14% longer than `wc -l` for the file I produced which was just long lines of commas and digits. IO should properly be done with `Pipes.ByteString` as the documentation says, the rest is conveniences of various sorts.

You can map an attoparsec parser over each line, distinguished by `view lines`, but keep in mind that an attoparsec parser can accumulate the whole text as it pleases and this might not be a great idea over a 1 gigabyte chunk of text.  If there is a repeated figure on each line (e.g. word separated numbers) you can use `Pipes.Attoparsec.parsed` to stream them.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try too when I get a chance